# Error 403 al subir proyecto codeigniter 4 a servidor

Tags: php, codeigniter, servidor, error-403

He creado un proyecto de codeigniter y al tratar de subirlo al servidor arroja error 403, he intentado modificar los parametros de .env de development a production, he cambiado la url base por la de la web y he colocado base de datos, usuario y contraseña.

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Example Environment Configuration file
#
# This file can be used as a starting point for your own
# custom .env files, and contains most of the possible settings
# available in a default install.
#
# By default, all of the settings are commented out. If you want
# to override the setting, you must un-comment it by removing the '#'
# at the beginning of the line.
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# ENVIRONMENT
# production / development
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

 CI_ENVIRONMENT = production #production

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# APP
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

 app.baseURL = 'http://web.es'
# If you have trouble with `.`, you could also use `_`.
# app_baseURL = ''
# app.forceGlobalSecureRequests = false

# app.sessionDriver = 'CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\FileHandler'
# app.sessionCookieName = 'ci_session'
# app.sessionExpiration = 7200
# app.sessionSavePath = null
# app.sessionMatchIP = false
# app.sessionTimeToUpdate = 300
# app.sessionRegenerateDestroy = false

# app.CSPEnabled = false

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# DATABASE
#--------------------------------------------------------------------


 database.default.hostname = localhost
 database.default.database = nombrebasededatos
 database.default.username = usuarioBD
 database.default.password = contraseña
 database.default.DBDriver = MySQLi
 database.default.DBPrefix =
# database.default.port = 3306


# database.tests.hostname = localhost
# database.tests.database = ci4_test
# database.tests.username = root
# database.tests.password = root
# database.tests.DBDriver = MySQLi
# database.tests.DBPrefix =
# database.tests.port = 3306

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONTENT SECURITY POLICY
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# contentsecuritypolicy.reportOnly = false
# contentsecuritypolicy.defaultSrc = 'none'
# contentsecuritypolicy.scriptSrc = 'self'
# contentsecuritypolicy.styleSrc = 'self'
# contentsecuritypolicy.imageSrc = 'self'
# contentsecuritypolicy.baseURI = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.childSrc = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.connectSrc = 'self'
# contentsecuritypolicy.fontSrc = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.formAction = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.frameAncestors = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.frameSrc = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.mediaSrc = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.objectSrc = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.pluginTypes = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.reportURI = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.sandbox = false
# contentsecuritypolicy.upgradeInsecureRequests = false
# contentsecuritypolicy.styleNonceTag = '{csp-style-nonce}'
# contentsecuritypolicy.scriptNonceTag = '{csp-script-nonce}'
# contentsecuritypolicy.autoNonce = true

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# COOKIE
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# cookie.prefix = ''
# cookie.expires = 0
# cookie.path = '/'
# cookie.domain = ''
# cookie.secure = false
# cookie.httponly = false
# cookie.samesite = 'Lax'
# cookie.raw = false

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# ENCRYPTION
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# encryption.key =
# encryption.driver = OpenSSL
# encryption.blockSize = 16
# encryption.digest = SHA512

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# HONEYPOT
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# honeypot.hidden = 'true'
# honeypot.label = 'Fill This Field'
# honeypot.name = 'honeypot'
# honeypot.template = '<label>{label}</label><input type="text" name="{name}" value=""/>'
# honeypot.container = '<div style="display:none">{template}</div>'

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# SECURITY
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# security.csrfProtection = 'cookie'
# security.tokenRandomize = false
# security.tokenName = 'csrf_token_name'
# security.headerName = 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'
# security.cookieName = 'csrf_cookie_name'
# security.expires = 7200
# security.regenerate = true
# security.redirect = true
# security.samesite = 'Lax'

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# LOGGER
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# logger.threshold = 4

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# CURLRequest
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# curlrequest.shareOptions = true
```

Tambien he modificado App/config/database.php con los datos de acceso de la base de datos,

```
public $default = [
        'DSN'      => '',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'usuarioBD',
        'password' => 'contraseña',
        'database' => 'nombrebasededatos',
        'DBDriver' => 'MySQLi',
        'DBPrefix' => '',
        'pConnect' => false,
        'DBDebug'  => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swapPre'  => '',
        'encrypt'  => false,
        'compress' => false,
        'strictOn' => false,
        'failover' => [],
        'port'     => 3306,
    ];
```

Esta sería la estructura de la carpeta del servidor, es decir he colocado mi proyecto en public_html, esta carpeta esta situada en la raiz de la web.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EL index.php estaría situado en App/views y .htcacces en App

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy realizando alguna cosa mal? O me faltaría alguna cosa? es la primera vez que subo un proyecto de codeingiter a producción.

EDIT: Después de investigar un poco más he visto que tenia que colocar.htacces y index.php en public_html.

Adjunto el [error](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/556700/fatal-error-require-failed-opening-required-home-customer-www-web-es-publi) que me ha surgido al colocarlo.

sigo dando un poco palos de ciego si alguien supiera ayudarme con lo que necesito hacer para poder tener funcional mi proyecto en el servidor.. Gracias

Comment: No veo un index.php ni un .htaccess... ¿cual se supone que es la página inicial?  Imagino que la tienes dentro de public_html/public

Comment: @masterguru no entendía porque me decias lo del .htacces ni el index he seguido buscando informacion aunque aun no lo tengo preparado y he visto que he de mover index.php y .htacces a la carpeta public_html, estaba en public anteriormente, esto sería correcto? necesitaría alguna cosa mas? estoy dando un poco palos de ciego la verdad. También me ha surgido otro error al realizar esto, así que he creado otra pregunta aparte de la inicial https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/556700/fatal-error-require-failed-opening-required-home-customer-www-web-es-publi

Comment: Sí, ya he visto la pregunta... No seguí contestándote porque no uso codeIgniter, pero cuando se accede a una carpeta debe haber un index.php o bien un .htaccess que redireccione donde corresponda, o bien ambos.  En cuanto a tu nueva pregunta, ¿no debería ser `require FCPATH . 'app/Config/Paths.php';`?  (de todos modos lo dudo, diria que debes buscar información y ejemplos sobre deploy de codeigniter, pues seguramente así tambien lo estamos haciendo mal)

Comment: @masterguru no te preocupes, muchas gracias por ayudarme a pesar de no usarlo, he probado esto que me comentabas del require pero no ha funcionado tampoco, igualmente gracias. Voy a ver si encuentro alguna cosa sobre deploy codeigniter.