# Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/customer/www/web.es/public_html/../app/Config/Paths.php' al usar HTTPS

Tags: php, codeigniter, hosting, https

Estoy usando codeigniter 4, y al subir mi proyecto al servidor y colocar el index.php y el.htcacces de la carpeta public donde estaban inicialmente a la carpeta public_html ha surgido un error. **Este error solo ocurre al usar HTTPS  y no http.** al usar http la web se visualiza correctamente.

El error completo sería el siguiente:

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
> '/home/customer/www/web.es/public_html/../app/Config/Paths.php'
> (include_path='.:/usr/local/php74/pear') in
> /home/customer/www/web.es/public_html/index.php on line 32

Esto ha ocurrido cuando he colocado el index.php y el .htcacces en la carpeta public_html de mi proyecto.

He ido a la linea indicada es decir la 32 de index.php donde aparecia lo siguiente:

```
require FCPATH . '../app/Config/Paths.php';
```

y la he modificado por esto otro:

```
require FCPATH . 'app/Config/Paths.php';
```

Pero el error sigue siendo el mismo, en https no funciona correctamente.

Esta sería la estructura del proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo Paths.php esta situado en la carpeta app/Config/Paths.php

Answer (score 0):

debes de verificar bien el archivos PATHS, yo tuve el mismo problema, pero seleccione bien la ruta. y me funciono de la siguiente manera:

```
require FCPATH . '../../app/Config/Paths.php';
```

tenia mi archivo 2 carpetas afuera y me funciono.